# How can I use the rename command with regex to remove the last part of a filename but keep the extension?

Tags: regex, unix

I have a list of files that use the following naming convention:

```
filename-test-12345.txt
```

I am trying to remove the "-test-12345" part of each file but keep the .txt extension.  I've tried to use the rename command with regex but unfortunately my syntax is incorrect:

```
rename -n 's/(.*).{15}$/$1.txt/' *
```

Does anyone know how to modify the regex to get it to display the desired output ie. `filename.txt`? I am not looking to write a script, as this is just a one off list of files in a folder that I need to rename.

Comment: What languages and platforms are you constrained to using? Given your mention of the `rename` command it seems like you are interested in solutions for Linux but since that command can also be installed on macOS perhaps that is also a constraint. This can be easily done using POSIX shell (e.g., Bash, Zsh) builtins without the need for an external command. Also, the use of a regex in this situation is almost certainly a mistake. Do you really want to strip the last 15 chars before the extension regardless of the specific chars? That seems fragile and likely to have unexpected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895) (usable in any OS):

```
rename -n 's/.{15}$/.txt/' *
```

or

```
rename -n 's/-\w+-\d+//' *
```

or

```
rename -n 's/^(\w+)-.*(\.txt)/$1$2/'
```

or

```
rename -n 'my @a = split /[-.]/; s/.*/"$a[0].$a[-1]"/' *
```

or better written:

```
rename -n 's/.*/join ".", +(split m|[-.]|)[0, -1]/e' *
```

##### Output:

```
rename(filename-test-12345.txt, filename.txt)
```

remove `-n` when happy with the output.

---

**If you don't have the good output, your `rename` implementation looks not the good one, check my link with deep explanations and how to use Perl's rename.**

---

##### Short regex memo:

- `\d`: a digit
- `\w`: word character: `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_`

Comment: @Gillies Thanks for the options.  The first suggestion is the easiest for me to understand.  I tried to verify the number of characters that "-test-12345.txt" has with `echo "-test-12345.txt" | wc -m` but I seems to be giving me one more than my count.  Any idea why that is the case?

Comment: Ugh! Long ago I used Perl as my primary non-compiled language. I stopped using it over a decade ago. I have no idea what market share Perl has today but recommending it as a dependency seems like a bad idea given that this problem can be easily solved without relying on a dying language.

Comment: We don't care about what you use or not @Kurtis. Perl is installed on a wide variety of Unix* and this is a good tool. And OP explicitly asked help with this command.

Comment: @Train: use `echo -n "-test-12345.txt" | wc -m` the `\n` is one char. Try to understand solution, it's the better one and not complicated. I added a regex memo (explanations)

Comment: @Gillies Thanks for point out the new line character that is inserted by echo. I am trying to understand the regex memo in the first example, `'s/.{15}$/.txt/' * `a bit more. I initially thought that `.` represents the current file and `*` represents all files in the current directory, but I also tried the command without the `*` at the end and it still renamed for all files. I am using the pearl version of rename on macos.

Comment: Gilles not Gillies, Perl not pearl. `.` is any character but `\n`